# .htaccess why problem when using ? in Redirect

Tags: redirect, .htaccess, mod-alias

i have this line

Redirect /?page=cms_page&id=12 http://www.domain.dk/case

when i type ?page=...... its not will work if i only use page=..... its will work fine but not the user type

domain.dk/?page=cms_page&id=12

So now i ask you guys what have i make wrong?

Answer (score 0):

With the directives of [mod_alias](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_alias.html) you can only test for the URI path but not the URI query. To do so, you can use [mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^page=cms_page&id=12$
RewriteRule ^$ http://www.example.com/case? [L,R]
```

The empty query in the substitution will avoid that the original query will automatically appended to the new URI. And the *R* flag will force an external redirect.